# BST to GMT Oracle Error (ORA-08186) whilst using a Flashback Query

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration, dst, rhel7

Hoping someone can enlighten me...

I arrived in the office this morning to find out that an automated (via OS CRON) SQL*Plus script had started failing at 0100BST and continued to do so until 0230BST during the switchover from BST to GMT with the following Oracle Error

```
"*ERROR at line 20:
ORA-08186: invalid timestamp specified"
```

The SQL below has had some identifying names redacted but is otherwise syntactically equal to that which failed.

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR( MIN(ioh.mdstamp), 'DD-MON-YY hh24:mi:ss')   First_Update
       , TO_CHAR( MAX(ioh.mdstamp), 'DD-MON-YY hh24:mi:ss')  Last_Update
       , ioh.consignment
       , ioh.order       
       , CASE ioh.ord_type
            WHEN 'T' THEN 'STORE MOVE'
            WHEN 'S' THEN 'CUST DEL'
         END                    Movement_Type
       , ioh.status             Order_Status         
       , ioh.site_id            Site
       , COUNT(\*)               Attempts
    FROM table1
         VERSIONS
          BETWEEN TIMESTAMP 
                  from_tz(cast((sysdate) as timestamp),'Europe/London') - INTERVAL '20' MINUTE
              AND MAXVALUE ioh
   WHERE versions_operation = 'I'
     And ioh.client_id      = 'client1'
     AND ioh.status         = 'Cancelled'
     AND ioh.MSTATUS        = 'Pending'     
GROUP BY ioh.consignment
       , ioh.order
       , ioh.ord_type
       , ioh.status         
       , ioh.site_id
ORDER BY ioh.consignment
       , ioh.order_id
       , 2
```

Environment is:

- OS: RHEL7.2
- DB: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit
  Production
- SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0

The script executes every 15mins within a BASH wrapper script called via the OS Cron.

```
sqlplus -s $CONNECT_DCS << ! >> ${f_SQLResults}
        @${SQL_SCRIPTS}/${__SCRIPTNAME_NOEXT}.sql;  
        exit;
!
```

Another script captured the OS's BST to DST Change:

```
---------------------------------------
Checking for rejections due to invalid address
Sun 27 Oct **01:47:11 BST** 2019
got count 0
0 - no rejections
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
Checking for rejections due to invalid address
Sun 27 Oct **01:02:10 GMT** 2019
got count 0
0 - no rejections
---------------------------------------
```

The failures started occurring at 0100h BST and continued to occur until what would have been 0230h BST if the change BST to DST change at 0200BST not occurred. As I'm ensuring the Timezone is 'Europe/London' i thought the DB would handle this DST Change automatically but I'm failing to understand why it didn't. One thought that did occur to me is that it may have something to do with using the MAX SCN value or the NLS_TERRITORY bwing set as 'AMERICA' although agian I'd have thought explicitly setting the timezone in the sql qwould have resolved this.

The following DB Config is set:

```
SQL> select dbtimezone from dual;

DBTIME
------
+00:00

1 row selected.

SQL> select sessiontimezone from dual;

SESSIONTIMEZONE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Europe/London

1 row selected.

SQL> select SYSTIMESTAMP from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
28-OCT-19 09.30.36.653265 AM +00:00

1 row selected.

SQL> !date
Mon 28 Oct 09:30:42 GMT 2019

SQL> set lines 200
SQL> l
  1* select * from v$nls_parameters
SQL> /

PARAMETER                                                        VALUE                                                                CON_ID
---------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
NLS_LANGUAGE                                                     AMERICAN                                                                  0
NLS_TERRITORY                                                    AMERICA                                                                   0
NLS_CURRENCY                                                     $                                                                         0
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY                                                 AMERICA                                                                   0
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS                                           .,                                                                        0
NLS_CALENDAR                                                     GREGORIAN                                                                 0
NLS_DATE_FORMAT                                                  DD-MON-RR                                                                 0
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE                                                AMERICAN                                                                  0
NLS_CHARACTERSET                                                 AL32UTF8                                                                  0
NLS_SORT                                                         BINARY                                                                    0
NLS_TIME_FORMAT                                                  HH.MI.SSXFF AM                                                            0

PARAMETER                                                        VALUE                                                                CON_ID
---------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT                                             DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM                                                  0
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT                                               HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR                                                        0
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT                                          DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR                                              0
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY                                                $                                                                         0
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET                                           AL16UTF16                                                                 0
NLS_COMP                                                         BINARY                                                                    0
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS                                             CHAR                                                                      0
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP                                              FALSE                                                                     0

19 rows selected.

SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'TZR')
--------------------------------
+00:00

1 row selected.

SQL> !date +"%Z %z"
GMT +0000

SQL> !timedatectl
      Local time: Mon 2019-10-28 11:57:36 GMT
  Universal time: Mon 2019-10-28 11:57:36 UTC
        RTC time: Mon 2019-10-28 11:57:36
       Time zone: Europe/London (GMT, +0000)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: no
 Last DST change: DST ended at
                  Sun 2019-10-27 01:59:59 BST
                  Sun 2019-10-27 01:00:00 GMT
 Next DST change: DST begins (the clock jumps one hour forward) at
                  Sun 2020-03-29 00:59:59 GMT
                  Sun 2020-03-29 02:00:00 BST

SQL>
```

If anyone can help I'd be really appreciative.

Cheers

PS: Just noticed that our glogin.sql has the following line: "alter session set time_zone='Europe/London';"

Comment: In an ideal world, when somebody tags a question here with `[database-administration]` the question wizard would pop up a suggestion that it might be better asked on the [DBA.SE site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I would suggest rather `BETWEEN TIMESTAMP 
                  (SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '20' MINUTE) AND MAXVALUE`, then you should not have any issue with time zones. Comparison of `TIMESTAMP WITH {LOCAL} TIME ZONE` are always performed at UTC.

Comment: @APC Thanks for the heads up. Only realised there was a dba site after I'd posted the question. I then added the tag later but no pop-up was displayed. I'd thought about re-posting there but wasn't sure if i would be breaking some house rules or not by having duplicate entries. #newbie

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks. I'm afraid i'm still not fully grasping this. using my code 'from_tz(cast((sysdate) as timestamp),'Europe/London') - INTERVAL '20' MINUTE' on 27/10/2019 at 0100h BST (27/10/2019 0000h UTC). if it is doing the conversion to UTC as you suggest surely it would have returned 27/10/2019 2340h UTC? Why then would it fail with "*ERROR at line 20: ORA-08186: invalid timestamp specified" as 0100h is a valid BST and UTC/GMT time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `NLS_TIME` and `NLS_TIMESTAMP` parameters. A quick workaround might be applied by issuing the following commands :

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIME_FORMAT         = 'HH24:MI:SSXFF';
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    = 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SSXFF';
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT      = 'HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR';
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR';
```

since you're looking for `HH24` format of hour

such as `TO_CHAR( MIN(ioh.mdstamp), 'DD-MON-YY hh24:mi:ss')` within the query.

Comment: thanks. 

Do they not just affect returned/displayed data though? 
My issue seems to be at the config/comparison stage - i think!

Comment: You're welcome @Mick . You can issue those commands just before running your script. Yes, those affect the current session only, but should work without issue. If you want to resolve globally ( 
throughout the DB ) you need alter system commands which are extremely dangerous, and should be consulted to the DBA .

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the commands thanks. what I don't understand is how they affect the comparison of date/time values across DST boundaries. I've always assumed those commands (perhaps wrongly) you listed are purely for display/output purposes. From what you're saying I would need to change the database territory to 'UNITED KINGDOM' for a global (system) solution- correct?

Comment: I've meant to change them not only for displaying purposes, but also affect the operation style within the current session @Mick. Have you ever tried ? Btw, I didn't tell anything about the territory but `NLS_TIME*` parameters.

Comment: Yeah...I know you didn't mention 'TERRITORY' but I'm aware those NLS_TIME* parameters you mentioned use it to derive a default output - from what I've been reading about them! thanks again.